# agora rtc Unhandled error PlatformException(2, invalid argument, null, null) on ios

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, agora.io

i get Unhandled error `PlatformException(2, invalid argument, null, null)` error using agora rtc on ios, it works on android without any error, below is my code

```
   final RtcEngine _engine = await RtcEngine.create(AGORA_RTC_APP_ID);
   await _engine .enableVideo();
   await _engine .enableAudio();
   await _engine .setChannelProfile(ChannelProfile.LiveBroadcasting);
   await _engine .setClientRole(ClientRole.Broadcaster);
   await _engine .muteLocalAudioStream(true);
   await _engine .enableWebSdkInteroperability(true);
   final configuration = VideoEncoderConfiguration();
   configuration.dimensions = VideoDimensions();
   await _engine .setVideoEncoderConfiguration(configuration);
   await _engine .joinChannel(
          token,
          channelName,
          null,
          userId,
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that I wasn't passing `VideoDimensions` parameters

`configuration.dimensions = VideoDimensions(width: 1920, height: 1080);`